# How to center a checkBox in a TableLayoutPanel, windows forms when form is resized?

Tags: winforms, user-controls, tablelayout

I have a UserControl. In it I have a TableLayoutPanel control with columns and rows. In cell I have basic windows forms controls like textboxes, comboBoxes and checkboxes.
For first two of them if I set their Anchor to **Top, Left, Right** they are re-sizing when the form is resized so the form looks ok.

Now, *I want that when the page is resized the CheckBox to be also in the middle of the cell*.
Mention: in each cell I have Panel control in which are placed a label control and one of three mentioned above. 
[image]

Comment: still looking for a solution :-?

Answer (score 0):

By default a checkBox control is set to align Top-Left. Set it to align none and it will do exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the checkbox select properties,

Under the properties windows, scroll down to the Anchor property

click arrow button, un-check the default Top and Left. Set it to "None"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1370894/setting-the-label-to-center-within-a-tablelayout-p