# How can I make a ComboBox filling the whole cell in a Windows Forms table layout?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, tablelayout

My ComboBoxes do not fill their table layout cells completely, unlike the buttons. You can see it in the screenshot.

Buttons and ComboBoxes are `Dock = Fill`, margins are the same, `anchor = top, left`.

How can I make them filling the entire cell?

[image: ComboBoxes in Table Layout]

Note: It is this "white space" below the ComboBox I want to get rid off.

Comment: For my own references: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14975024/356726

Comment: WinForms (and User32) ComboBoxes are width sizable only.  Their vertical sizing is based on the vertical size of the font they are configured to use.  Single line text boxes act the same way.  You can change this behavior by hooking the DrawItem and MeasureItem events.  I don't have a clue how you'd wire that up to get the behavior you want.  Hopefully you can use this as hints

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65504400/i-am-unable-to-dock-a-combobox-in-a-tablelayoutpanel-cell

Comment: You (Pavan) could post the link as answer. All details are indeed there. I would accept it. Cheers.